# Laravel - Bootstrap tabs Ajax content loaded dynamically

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-tabs

Bootstrap tabs- Ajax content loaded dynamically using

```
 $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);             
    });
    $this.tab('show');
```

What should be done to redirect to new window in case of session invalid to login instead of loading the login in the tab

Home controller:

```
public function ReturnView() 
{
    if(Session::has('user_data')){
        return view('pages.dashboard');
    }
    else {
        return view('pages.login')->with('message', 'login');
    }           


}
```

Comment: do you want to redirect from ajax if session is invalid to login??

Comment: I guess you can do this from javascript .. by checking if session exists or not by assigning some userid or something in javascript and in js response if it does not find or exists then simply redirect to login page instead of showing the tab content in response of js.

Comment: yes @MittulAtTechnoBrave that's why i asked

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the response from the controller with your javascript and if the condition for redirection is satisfied. you can redirect using `location.replace`

something like this

```
window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
```